# What is the form for a throwing raiseKEY validation func in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, kvc

I'm going through the Hillegass book, 5th Edition, 10th Chapter, RaiseMan example.

He indicates this Swift 2 code:

`class Employee: NSObject {
    var name: String? = "New Employee"
    var raise: Float = 0.05
}
//
//func validateRaise(raiseNumberPointer: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSNumber?>, error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
//

//    let raiseNumber = raiseNumberPointer.pointee
//    if raiseNumber == nil {
//        let domain = "UserInputValidationErrorDomain"
//        let code = 0
//        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "An employee's raise must be a number."]
//        outError?.pointee = NSError(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: userInfo)
//        return false
//    }
//

//    return true
//}`

which doesn't work in Xcode 8.1, Swift 3.0.1, of course. So I tried:

```

enum EmployeeError: Error {
    case badRaise

}

func validateRaise(raiseNumberPointer: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer)  throws  {

```
let i = 1

do {
    guard let raiseNumber =  try raiseNumberPointer.pointee else {
        throw EmployeeError.badRaise
    }
    let domain = "UserInputValidationErrorDomain"
    let code = 0
    let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "An employee's raise must be a number."]
}
```

}

```

but setting a breakpoint showed me that this code is never called. In IB, obviously, I went to the appropriate NSTextField and checked off validate immediately, as instructed. this is the error I got:

```

2016-11-02 07:46:31.163900 RaiseMan[19240:1489479] [General] An uncaught exception was raised

2016-11-02 07:46:31.163986 RaiseMan[19240:1489479] [General] [ setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key raise.

```

if someone knows the right syntax, that would be very helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another user found this on the Big Nerd Ranch site and sent it to me on Slack.

https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/validateraise-function-changes-in-swift-3-exception-is-not-being-handled/9279